# Analyze .exe/.dll (Windows PE) files for code bloats

Tags: windows, performance, low-level, diagnostics, dumpbin

Let's say I have a project with a dozen of different modules which produce one resultant DLL, how can I analyze it so that I can identify the actual file size that each module/functions contribute? I know it might be impossible with a Release build where much information has been stripped, but how about if I have the full source and can do a Debug build?

Also, if there are big static variables defined somewhere, is there a way I can easily locate them?

*Bonus question*: How about Linux ELF files?

Comment: dumpbin should IMHO show you big global/statics.

Comment: @valdo any details on how to do it? I've explored a bit and couldn't seem to figure it out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Whenever I've been involved in identifying bloat I generally start with [dumpbin](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c1h23y6c%28VS.71%29.aspx) on Windows. Usually by writing a tool to examine each object module via [dumpbin](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c1h23y6c%28VS.71%29.aspx) then analyse the output. It tends to be an iterative process and can take a fair amount of time.

For debug builds with PDB [Sizer](http://aras-p.info/projSizer.html) can produce useful reports.

Adrian has some useful guidance here. [Minimizing Code Bloat for Faster Builds and Smaller Executables](http://gameangst.com/?p=46) and a tool called [SymbolSort](http://gameangst.com/?p=320) to help. The source in C# is included with SymbolSort so that may be a good place to start if SymbolSort doesn't help.

For ELF the output of [nm](http://cf.ccmr.cornell.edu/cgi-bin/w3mman2html.cgi?nm%281%29) and [objdump](http://cf.ccmr.cornell.edu/cgi-bin/w3mman2html.cgi?objdump%281%29) are a good starting point.

Comment: This is absolutely fantastic! They have this stupid 24 hour policy for bounty :P

Comment: Just took a look at `nm -S`. What a simple problem that is so obscure to solve on Windows :P